# How to make this layout using XAML and Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to ask how can I make a design similar to the below image using XAML and Xamarin?

I mean a main image image and a profile image on the top of it with half of it only.. and the news title is on the main image then at the top right corner there is the news time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this into `ContentPage`:

```xml
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- header content -->
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="End" Text="8 hours ago" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- body content -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Source="xamarin.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <!-- profile image -->
        <Image Source="usermale.png" 
               VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start"
               HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"
               TranslationY="50"/>
 </Grid>
```

Yuo will get this:

[image]